# Custom progress bar - Trapeze

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like to make my progress bar like the one in the image, but can't seem to figure out how.

[image: Custom progress bar - Trapeze]

For the moment, my progress drawable looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

which makes the progress bar rectangle. The problem is adding the part in the right.

Sure, I can make a custom view, and draw the shape using path, then implement the progress functionality myself, but there's gotta be simpler way, right?

Comment: Tried it, couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simpler ways:

1. Your can use animation to make it. Use a set of progress animation images , then use a frame animation, and start animation to show the progress.
2. Use a progress image, and write a custom view in which you rotate an ImageView that holds the image (or you draw a bitmap and rotate it).